How to implement video Scrubbing in AEM Assets?
We currently use asset-share-commons as a front end to our AEM Assets DAM. I'd like to swap/update the web player to allow for a video scrubber that provides a thumbnail preview as you mouse over the video timeline. I've read many different ideas for a solution and have yet to land on something successful. We do use workflows to generate the web friendly video rendition. We are hosted on-prem (v6.5) and cannot use S7 (Dynamic Media) at all. We are limited to ffmpeg/imagemagick for rendition workflow processing.
Has anyone successfully done this and can you point me in the right direction?
I have tried to modify AEM workflow video profiles to try to generate extra thumbnails in order to try Scrubbing HTML5 video, however the thumbnails are not saved back to the asset.
